# String interpolation in a large JSON string

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to replace a variable in a large search string I will be using to call Elastic Search, but I can't seem to get the variable into the string.  Below is what I have attempted, using string interpolation to try and add `my_var` into the search string at 3 different places.

```
    my_var = "foo"
    
    search_string = '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"some_status", "query":{"bool":{"must":{"terms":{"status.code":["ACTIVE"]}}}}}}, {"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"path":"acc", "query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase":{"acc.name.text":"{#my_var}"}}]}}}}, {"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase":{"name.stuff":"{#my_var}"}}]}}, {"nested":{"path":"trade_names", "query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase":{"some_names.some_name.stuff":"{#my_var}"}}]}}}}]}}]}}}'

    JSON.parse(search_string)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's `#{my_var}`, not `{#my_var}`.

Beside that typo, string interpolation needs `"..."`, it is disabled in `'...'`:

```
foo = 123

str = "foo = #{foo}"   # <- turns #{foo} into 123
#=> "foo = 123"

str = 'foo = #{foo}'   # <- keeps #{foo} literally
#=> "foo = \#{foo}"
```

Since your string contains many literal double quote characters, using `"..."` would add a lot of escape characters.

Apart from quotes, you could use the [percent string](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) `%Q(...)`:

```
str = %Q({"foo":"#{foo}"})
#=> "{\"foo\":\"123\"}"
```

or a [heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents+-28heredocs-29): (using `JSON` as the delimiter might enable syntax highlighting in your editor)

```
str = <<-JSON.chomp
  {"foo":"#{foo}"}
JSON
#=> "{\"foo\":\"123\"}"
```

Another option is to construct a Ruby hash and turn that into JSON:

```
require 'json'

hash = { 'foo' => foo }

str = hash.to_json
#=> "{\"foo\":123}"
```

The JSON library also handles escaping for you.